# VF Page with Enhanced List - Set return location on Save or Cancel

Tags: apex, visualforce, enhancedlist

I have a custom visualforce page which is an enhanced list that displays one of my Case List Views on the Home tab of SF.

```
<apex:page >
        <apex:enhancedList customizable="false" listId="00B4E000000LjGD" height="400" rowsPerPage="10" />
        <base target="_parent" />
</apex:page>
```

It looks like:
[image]

My Issue occurs when I try to perform either Change Owner or Change Status of a case ticket from this screen. If I Save or Cancel either of these opperations I get sent to the following screen.

[image]

As you can see above, only the related list is displayed, I dont have the header or side bar, which I would like to see. 
Is anyone aware of how I can return the user to the SF Home Tab or display the header and sidebar on Save/Cancel from an action on the Enhanced List within a VF Page.

Thanks in advance

Comment: That piece of code perfectly works for me for change owner and change status click and return. I guess you haven't shared the full/correct code. First image is showing standard SFDC url. Put your screenshot showing visualforce url

Comment: Hi Santanu, Here is a screenshot of the VF page setup (http://i.imgur.com/31KAhjW.png)